# Swift 2.1 Selecting Options from Image Icons in a View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

If I wanted to have a screen with a number of options displayed via icons to present to the user to select from. What would be the best way to do this?

For instance if I had 6 different images with varying price ranges like $25 - $35, $35 - 50, $50 - $75 and so on and I wanted them to select one of these ranges, what would one suggest I use in this situation? A tableview? A collectionview? Is there a way to use a collectionview in this manner?

Comment: Is there some reason this was marked down? Seriously... I'll never get why some people mark some questions down. If it's a duplicate then mark it duplicate and I'll delete it. I didn't see this answered anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally depend on your app requirement and UI. you can use `tableview`, `collectionView`, or `scrollview`.

you just need to manage the selection of the item. For that you should use `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`. Where `NSDictionary` having a key called `selected` which is set to `true` when item get `selected`. When any other object get `selected` you make a loop which make all object `selected` to `false`. and then set the selected object to `true`.